# c strcat with pointer

Tags: c, pointers, strcat

I'm trying to use pointers and strcat from C. This is part of my learning process.

The idea is the user inputs a string that contains digits and the output should return only the digits.
So, if the user inputs
`te12abc` the output should be `12`.

This is my first try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main()
{
    char palavra[SIZE];
    char palavra2[SIZE];
    char *pont = palavra;
    char *pont2 = palavra2;

    printf("Insert the string\n");
    scanf("%s", palavra);

    do{
        if (isdigit(*pont)){
            strcat(palavra2, *pont);
        }
        *pont++;
    }while (*pont != '\0');

    printf("\nThe number is:\n%s\n", palavra2);
    return 0;
}
```

I believe that the pointer is working as expected but can't understand why strcat is not working.

Made a second try that is the program finds a number, stores that char in one variable and only then try to use strcat with that variable. Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    char palavra[SIZE];
    char palavra2[SIZE];
    char temp;
    char *pont = palavra;
    char * pont2 = &temp;

    printf("Insert the string\n");
    scanf("%s", palavra);

    do{
        if (isdigit(*pont)){
            temp = *pont;
            strcat(palavra2, pont2);
        }
        *pont++;
    }while (*pont != '\0');

    printf("\nThe number is:\n%s\n", palavra2);
    return 0;
}
```

Once again it gives me problems at strcat.

Made one last attempt but without pointer and still strcat does not work. Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char palavra[SIZE];
    char palavra2[SIZE];
    char temp;

    printf("Insert the string\n");
    scanf("%s", palavra);

    do{
        if (isdigit(palavra[i])){
            temp = palavra[i];
            strcat(palavra2, palavra[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }while (palavra[i] != '\0');

    printf("\nThe number is:\n%s\n", palavra2);
    return 0;
}
```

Can you point me to the right direction? Don't now what more can I do..

Regards,

favolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove * (dereference),

```
        strcat(palavra2, pont);
```

strcat expects a `char*` not a `char`
but this version appends the whole rest.
you have to create a nul-terminated string.

And the * is useless

```
    *pont++;
```

This does the job

```
    pont++;
```

now all at once

```
int main()
{
  char palavra[SIZE];
  char palavra2[SIZE];
  char c2[2] = "a";
  char *pont = palavra;
  char *pont2 = palavra2;

  printf("Insert the string\n");
  scanf("%s", palavra);

  do{
    if (isdigit(*pont)){
      c2[0] = *pont;
      strcat(palavra2, c2);
    }
    pont++;
}while (*pont != '\0');

printf("\nThe number is:\n%s\n", palavra2);
return 0;
```

However, this is too complicated

```
int main()
{
  char palavra[SIZE];
  char palavra2[SIZE];


  printf("Insert the string\n");
  scanf("%s", palavra);

  char *pont = palavra;
  char *pont2 = palavra2;

  while (true) {
    char c = *pont ++;
    if (c == 0) break;
    if (isdigit(c)){
       *pont2++ = c;
    }
  };
  printf("\nThe number is:\n%s\n", palavra2);
  return 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're making it harder than it has to be. You don't need `strcat`:

```
/* Untested. */   
char *pont = palavra;
char *pont2 = palavra2;

while (*pont) {
    if (isdigit(*pont))
        *pont2++ = *pont;

    pont++;
}
*pont2 = 0;
```

Comment: A small issue, as I understand, the OP would like to append all digits in the string, so e.g. "a1b2c3d" would do three appends. `while(*pont){ if (isdigit(*pont)) { *pont2++ = *pont; } ++pont; } *pont2 = 0;`, I think.

Comment: @cnicutar Thanks This works but if i insert `te1te2te3te4te5` the program crashes. I believe it's because the size of the string is defined to be less than 10

Answer (score 3):

Your **third try** is almost correct.

Replace

```
strcat(palavra2, palavra[i]);
```

with

```
strncat(palavra2, palavra+i,1);
```

I am passing `palavra+i` and not `palavra[i]` cos the former is a progressing pointer and the latter is a character and `strncat` needs pointers

This is a nice example to illustrate **how to concatenate a string and a character**

Also,  make sure you always initialize your variables

```
char palavra[SIZE]="";
char palavra2[SIZE]="";
```

Comment: `strcat(palavra2, palavra+i,1)` Gives error `error: too many arguments to function 'strcat'`

Comment: I said `strncat` and not `strcat` :)

Comment: My bad :) it works but the problem is as the all others. If i insert  `te1te2te3te4te5` the program crashes

Comment: It works! See [this](http://ideone.com/PCUFn) Just change `SIZE` to some bigger value, say 20.

Comment: I know it works changing SIZE. Sorry for not telling that earlier. I want to keep `SIZE` at 10

Comment: Common @Favolas, how can you write a 15 byte string into a 10 byte string?

Answer (score 3):

**Porblems with your code: (1st version)**

1) You do `strcat` but `*pont` refers to single char, which is not a null-terminated string.

2) You do `*pont++;` But *pont is a value, not a pointer.

Do this change to the 1st version: It should be ok.

```
 do{
        if (isdigit(*pont)){
            *pont2=*pont;
             pont2++;
        }
        pont++; 
    }while (*pont != '\0');

*pont2='\0';
```

Comment: pont2 should be incremented only if a char was copied (i.e. isdigit(*pont))

Comment: @Thiruvalluvar Thanks This works but if i insert te1te2te3te4te5 the program crashes. I believe it's because the size of the string is defined to be less than 10. Shouldn't it stops at `*pont != '\0'`?

Comment: yes, that's right. You can use malloc() to allocate memory dynamically or increase the SIZE value.

Comment: No. There's no '\0' until the end of the string. '\0' is there only at the end of string "te1te2te3te4te5" which would have overwritten some other portion of memory that doesnt belong to your program. It may work sometimes. But it's clearly wrong.